# how to get class modal-backdrop which is coming from ng-bootstrap when we click on popup modal angular 5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

actually i am using ng-bootstrap for modal in angular 5. actually i want to add some css in existing class 'modal-backdrop' which comes when click on popup modal service for open from ng-bootstrap library , but not getting when do like document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0]; getting undefined because asynchronous call. i think when i call open method call first const head = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0];  then this.modalService.open() service , what can i do Please help me for this ?

```
open() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.modal, {
    windowClass: 'confirmation_popup',
    centered: true
});
const head = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can add in options **windowClass** and **backdropClass**, e.g.

```
this.modalService.open(content, 
     { windowClass: 'dark-modal',
       backdropClass: 'light-blue-backdrop' }
);
```

Ah!, don't forget add in your component ViewEncapsulation.None(*)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-options',
  templateUrl: './modal-options.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None //<--this line
})
```

or included the .css in your file **styles.css**

(*)This makes that all the .css in your component is translated to all your app.

Comment: Hi , this is fine , i want change in existing class so getting undefined because when we click on open method the calling const head = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0]; and after that modal popup is opning ,  actully in first , should be call this line  this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(this.modal, {
    windowClass: 'confirmation_popup',
    centered: true
}); then const head = document.getElementsByClassName('confirmation-pupup')[0]; , automaticall will get class

Comment: @MohammadParvej, use `document.getElementsByClassName` it's not an "angular way'", You can get a reference of head using ViewChild or another way

Comment: by the using we can do document.querySelector('body').children[8].getElementsByClassName('confirmation_popup') and modify that call , but getting before call open but when we click on that method not get undefined may be inside method Ascn call using so i dont which line will be executed first